# How to use pandas_profiling with a large database table

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I'm trying to use pandas_profiling to profile a table.
It has around 20 columns most of them are float and almost 3 millions records.

I got the following error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "V:\Python\prof.py", line
>   53, in 
>       if **name** == "**main**": main()   File "V:\Python\prof.py", line 21, in main
>       df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)   File "C:\Users\linus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py",
>   line 380, in read_sql
>       chunksize=chunksize)   File "C:\Users\linus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py",
>   line 1477, in read_query
>       data = self._fetchall_as_list(cursor)   File "C:\Users\linus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py",
>   line 1486, in _fetchall_as_ list
>       result = cur.fetchall() MemoryError

I have tried with less record it worked.

Is there a way to bypass this error ? It looks like it is a memory limitation.
Can we do that another way ? Or it is impossible with Python ?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the position to provide information so that we can replicate the error, we can resolve it. I would recommend opening an issue on the [github page](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues).

*Disclose: I am co-author of this package.*